# Extract second best workflow. Tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels

Trying to figure out how to extract the workflow which is based on the second best tuneparams. By default `select_best` returns the first rank, which is not what i want.
Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Please specify what the return should be. Give an example. It is unclear to me based on the description and the picture given.

Comment: `select_best()` seems to be calling `show_best(..., n=1)`. You won't be able to get more than one return value out of it, but if you just call `show_best(..., n=2)` and select the second element that should be what you want. Alternatively, what's wrong with selecting for `rank == 2` in what you are showing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if this helps in your case.

```
library(tidymodels)


chi_features_res |> 
  rank_results(rank_metric = "rmse") |> 
  filter(.metric == "rmse" & rank == 2)
```